# Python Script is going into incorrect if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I have a code that will allow the user to input a name, and based off of the name that is input, the script will perform different actions. For simplicity I've placed the snippet that is working incorrectly below.

```
print system
if "KH" or "Oberon" or "Bearcat" in system:
    print"Type 2"
elif "Sentry" in system:
    print"Type 1"
```

The user inputs Sentry but the script keeps falling in the "Type 2" statement. The print System command is outputting Sentry so i don't quite understand why its not doing the right thing here.

Comment: This is a hard to find dupe ... Basically, your `or` statements aren't doing what you think they are.  you want something like `if any(substr in system for substr in ('KH', 'Oberon', 'Bearcat'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `or` expressions aren't doing what you think they are.  Python reads this as:

```
if "KH" or ("Oberon" or ("Bearcat" in system)):
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if "KH":
```

since `"KH"` is truthy and the `or` operator short circuits.  One fix is something like:

```
if any(substr in system for substr in ('KH', 'Oberon', 'Bearcat')):
```

Comment: Your solution and explanation here works. I question however how this is possible to pass as true, as system does not hold the string KH, would it not produce False for that first if statement?

Comment: @bladexeon -- Sorry, I had my [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code to this:

```
if "KH" in system or "Oberon" in system or "Bearcat" in system:
```

Currently your code does this

```
if ("KH") or ("Oberon") or ("Bearcat" in system):
```

which always evaluates to `true` as both `"KH"` and `"Oberon"` are non-empty strings.

Comment: Little nitpick: Using an tuple instead of a list for the in check would be enough and IMHO also the logical choice for this, as the values aren't going to change.

Comment: Thanks @mgilson, I removed it. Didn't have time to test it as something urgent popped up.